# Subsequent calls to Geb Spock Test from GroovyConsole fail with UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I'm running the below script (a `GebReportingSpec` test case) from within `GroovyConsole.exe`. It runs properly the first time, when GroovyConsole is launched. It opens up FF, runs the scenario, and then closes FF on quitting the browser.

However, when I run the same script again from the same GroovyConsole, I get an `UnreachableBrowserException`. It first calls `setupSpec()` method, and then on calling the `go` method inside the test case, it calls `cleanupSpec()`...

**GEB**:
    0.9.0

**Selenium**:
    2.26.0

**Groovy**:
2.0.5

**FF**:
14.0.1

**JDK**:
1.6.0_37 64-Bit

**Script**:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab("org.gebish:geb-core:0.9.0"),
    @Grab("org.gebish:geb-spock:0.9.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.26.0"),
    //@Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.26.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.26.0")
])
import geb.Browser
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*

class Google_Search_Test extends GebReportingSpec {
def setupSpec() {
    println "Inside setupSpec()..."
    browser.config.autoClearCookies = true
}

def cleanupSpec() {
    println "Inside cleanupSpec()..."
    println "Quitting browser..."
    browser.quit()
}

def "google_search_wikipedia"() {
    println "Inside google_search_wikipedia..."
    when:
        println "Going to google.com..."
        go "http://google.com/ncr"

        // make sure we actually got to the page
        assert title == "Google"

        // enter wikipedia into the search field
        $("input", name: "q").value("wikipedia")

        // wait for the change to results page to happen
        // (google updates the page dynamically without a new request)
        waitFor { title.endsWith("Google Search") }

        // is the first link to wikipedia?
        def firstLink = $("li.g", 0).find("a.l")
    then:
        firstLink.text() == "Wikipedia"
        println "Finished test execution..."

}
}
```

**GebConfig.groovy**:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*
import java.util.concurrent.*

driver = { 
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile()
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.frameElement", "allAccess")

    def driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile)
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    driver
}

waiting {
    // all values are in seconds
    timeout = 60
    retryInterval = 0.5
}

reportsDir = "SeleniumReports"
```

**Successful run**:

```
Inside setupSpec()...
Inside google_search_wikipedia...
Going to google.com...
Finished test execution...
Inside cleanupSpec()...
Quitting browser...
JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 0, Time: 15739
```

**Subsequent runs (Exception)**:

```
Inside setupSpec()...
Inside google_search_wikipedia...
Going to google.com...
Inside cleanupSpec()...
Quitting browser...
JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 2, Time: 687
Test Failure: google_search_wikipedia(Google_Search_Test)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18040', time: '2012-11-02 09:44:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:275)
    at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:371)
    at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:363)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
    at Google_Search_Test.google_search_wikipedia(Google_Search.groovy:27)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called.
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18040', time: '2012-11-02 09:44:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:351)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:505)
    ... 5 more

Test Failure: google_search_wikipedia(Google_Search_Test)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18040', time: '2012-11-02 09:44:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:535)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:396)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.getPageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:42)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writePageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:38)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writeReport(PageSourceReporter.groovy:29)
    at geb.report.CompositeReporter.writeReport(CompositeReporter.groovy:31)
    at geb.Browser.report(Browser.groovy:698)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.report(GebReportingSpec.groovy:43)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.cleanup(GebReportingSpec.groovy:39)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called.
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18040', time: '2012-11-02 09:44:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:351)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:505)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: why do you need `driver` after `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` on GebConfig.groovy ?

Comment: @amisuno, if I do not return the driver object after setting the timeouts, Geb is unable to create the driver and I get the exception `DriverCreationException: callback script... returned 'org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$1$1@18a3fe6' which is not a WebDriver implementation
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geb has a concept of [driver caching](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/configuration.html#driver_caching) so that only one browser window is opened and reused and you're hitting a problem with using it from groovy console. Geb manages driver/browser instances for you and the cache is active throughout the life of the VM. You are getting the error because you are manually quitting the driver (which shouldn't be done if driver cache is enabled) and the VM has not been shut down (groovy console is still running between the two executions) which means that the browser managed by the driver retrieved from cache has been shut down.

You have two options here, the second better in my opinion:

- do not quit the driver - one browser window will be opened and reused across the subsequent executions of your tests
- use a build system, for example [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) (an example Geb project built using Gradle is avaialable [here](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle)) - this will shut down the VM after execution of your test(s) and it will also automatically shut down the browser

Comment: Thanks @erdi! I ended up doing what you suggested in your first option. In any case, I just needed it for a demo, which was why I was running it in GroovyConsole. You're right in that a better way of running these tests is as part of the build system. That's what I'm planning to do as well. We're moving to Maven soon, and will be looking at integrating these test cases with the build system. The combination of Geb, Spock, Groovy and Selenuim is really cool!

Comment: I just noticed that running these scripts from GroovyConsole causes groovyConsole.exe to still be in memory even after I close the editor.